# QGIS/GDAL Python- Export WMTS to geopackage raster, only for set extent and resolution

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, geopackage

The problem: I need to export imagery from a WMTS or XYZ webtile source for a variety of geographically dispersed areas. It will be used in Qfield, so needs to exported as a geopackage raster.

1. In QGIS, there is an option to use GDALs translate to convert to Geopackage. Is there a way to set a geographic extent and output resolution?
2. There is also the option, via the right-click menu or the layer menu, to 'save as' the image to geopackage (with a set extent and resolution).
   Is there a way to invoke this command via python?

Comment: Gdal_translate has options `-tr` and `-projwin` https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html.

Comment: You can use [Atlas](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/training_manual/forestry/forest_maps.html)

Answer (score 0):

[MapProxy](https://mapproxy.org/) is the perfect tool for this task. With the command line tool [mapproxy-seed](https://mapproxy.org/docs/1.13.0/seed.html) you can store specific areas and zoom levels into a GeoPackage file for later use in QGIS. If you want to use a [coverage](https://mapproxy.org/docs/1.13.0/coverages.html) from a geospatial datasource (i.e. PostGIS, GeoPackage), you have to install GDAL/OGR as well. You don't need to install MapProxy in production, because it's equipped with a test server. The only downside is, you have to manually configure your source (see [examples](https://mapproxy.org/docs/1.13.0/configuration_examples.html)).